# How to backup Gmail Account onto a hard drive?

Tags: macos, backup, gmail

I need to backup all the emails of my Gmail account on my hard drive. My Gmail is almost full and I need to clear all the data, but first I need to do a backup so that I can recover the emails later if I want to.

How can I accomplish this on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Google offer [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) which allows you to backup all data off Google (including Gmail, Google drive, etc) - and store it locally on your machine.

The Gmail data (MBOX format) can then be re-imported to a local email client (that understand MBOX format) so you can still view them.